# All internal users-Public group missing

Tags: community

I cannot see 'All Internal Users' when i try to share a report folder and select public group type
What could be the possible reason?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just found this now
https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=partner_portal_partner_users.htm&language=en_US

This all internal user group is created only after portals are enabled.

Although in developer edition,it is by default there,even without communities enabled.